# How to get Documents filtered by the top-most and sort embedded result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**Assumed i have the following Document structure.**

```
{
    "_id" : "ehbpidnopgpgcghgakiiiallielefonk",
    "users" : 11.87,
    "ratingTopMost" : {
        "average" : NumberInt("4"),
        "users" : NumberInt("3174"),
    },
    "reviews" : {
        "average" : NumberInt("5"),
        "count" : NumberInt("51"),
        "comments" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b87b1a07267ad001da7e733"),
                "name" : "Batista1395",
                "comment" : "Great Stackoverflow",
                "datum" : ISODate("2017-01-16T00:00:00.000+01:00"),
                "rating" : NumberInt("3")
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b87b1a07267ad001da7e732"),
                "name" : "Tim Ace",
                "comment" : "I Like it.",
                "datum" : ISODate("2016-08-17T00:00:00.000+02:00"),
                "bewertung" : NumberInt("5")
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

I need to **query** the top **most 20 documents** with the following criteria:

1. Top most value for rantingTopMost.average
2. Top most value for ratingTopMost.users
3. Top most value for reviews.count
4. Top most value for reviews.average
5. Top most value for users

The priority should from top to bottom (1 to 5).

Nice to have too: sort the embedded comments by Date DESC.

Comment: what should be the expected output?

Comment: Like the code shows. Have about 200 Records the same structure shown above.

The expected output should the records like shown above, but with the criteria above